# Javascript substring doesn't return the correct string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

i was manipulating the text in this document `http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/brook/11brook.html`, while i noticed something strange.
I was looking at the beginning of the article, in particular here:

```
Michelle Brook
The Content Mine
michelle@contentmine.org
...

(I am using jquery xpath)

var string=$("document").xpath("form[1]/table[3]/tr/td/table[5]/tr/td/table[1]/tr/td[2]/p[2]").html();
var new_string=string.substring(0,14);
```

I would expect that `new_string` was "Michelle Brook", but it was "Michelle Bro".
Why that? Is there a particular char that makes `string.substring()` fail?

Comment: Why don't you `console.log()` the string *before* you call `.substring()` and see what it really contains?

Comment: I suspect there are several sequential instances of whitespace that gets collapsed when rendered, but still exist in the source string.

Comment: @Pointy I have done that and string was the full html of the paragraph that i was looking. It was correct.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am thinking the same thing: how can i solve the problem?

Comment: `for(var x=0;x<14;x++) console.log(string.CharAt(x));`

Comment: @RobertMcKee i have already done that: in that way i see M_i_c_h_e_l_l_e_ _B_r_o_o_k and so the space is only one

Comment: CharAt will print the character codes, not the single character, try what I put again.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I think you're thinking of `.charCodeAt()`

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, try `.charCodeAt()`.  Specifically, I'm looking for character codes like 8206.

Comment: @RobertMcKee .charCodeAt(10) is 32

Comment: @ScTALE is `.charCodeAt(0)` 8206 or 65279?

Comment: @RobertMcKee no, it is 10

Comment: Well, there is your answer.  You have a linefeed as your first character.  I'm guessing `.charCodeAt(1)` is also another odd character (10,13,or 8206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to remove all leading and trailing whitespace from your string before trying to substring it:

```
var new_string=string.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '').substring(0,14);
```

Comment: I have understand the problem: does your code delete all character that can make substring() fail?

Comment: substring isn't failing.

Comment: using that replace, in different parts of the document i can see some &nbsp; word: why? how can i delete them?

Comment: I would suggest using an HTML parser instead of trying to use XPATH to parse your document.

Comment: `string.trim().substring(0,14);`  is shorter

Comment: @RobertMcKee i haven't understand what should i do

Comment: @Saba Trim() seems works only with .text() and not with .html()